# PIC Microcontroller C program Problem.[Sequential Issue and PWM Problem]

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, interrupts, pickit

I have just started coding PIC microcontroller in C and do not understand where the problem is.

PIC10F320 is chosen for its two PWM pins, one for breathing effect on LED and the other one for 75% duty cycle. Both are initiated after a certain time frame using TMR0 interrupt for a counter.

The problem is that the counter does not seem to work. The circuit goes right into the PWM sequence, skipping all the precondition in the program. Also, the touch sensor does not respond to reset the timer. Also, the PWM 75% cycle behavior is virtually non-existent as the oscilloscope shows a straight line pretty much.

I'd greatly appreciate it if someone can tell me what I did wrong.

```
// CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSC  // Oscillator Selection 
#pragma config BOREN = ON     // Brown-out Reset
#pragma config WDTE = OFF     // Watchdog Timer
#pragma config PWRTE = ON     // Power-up Timer
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF    // MCLR Pin Function Select bit->MCLR pin function is digital input, MCLR internally tied to VDD
#pragma config CP = OFF       // Code Protection 
#pragma config LVP = OFF      // Low-Voltage Programming 
#pragma config LPBOR = ON     // Brown-out Reset Selection bits
#pragma config BORV = LO      // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection
#pragma config WRT = OFF      // Flash Memory Self-Write Protection

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.
#include <xc.h>
#include <pic10f320.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000
#define SWITCH PORTAbits.RA2
#define PWMPin PORTAbits.RA1
#define LEDPin PORTAbits.RA0

void setup(void);

void setup(void) {    
    // disable analog - Set A.1 as output 
    ANSELAbits.ANSA1 = 0;
    ANSELAbits.ANSA0 = 0;
    
    TRISAbits.TRISA0 = 0; // LED O/P
    TRISAbits.TRISA1 = 0; // PWM O/P
    TRISAbits.TRISA2 = 1; // Switch I/P
    
    // Clear out the duty cycle registers
    PWM2DCH = 0x00;
    PWM2DCL = 0x00;
    
    PWM1DCH = 0x00;
    PWM1DCL = 0x00;
    
    PR2 = 52;   
    T2CONbits.T2CKPS = 0b00;
    T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 0x01;

    PWM2CONbits.PWM2OE = 0x01;  // PWM2 Turn on 
    PWM2CONbits.PWM2EN = 0x01;  // PWM2 Enable Output

    PWM1CONbits.PWM1OE = 0x01;  // PWM1 Turn on 
    PWM1CONbits.PWM1EN = 0x01;  // PWM1 Enable Output
    
    /*
     * My Calculations:
     * At 8MHz, Tosc is 125ns, Tcyc=4*Tosc=500ns.
     * With PR2=52decimal, prescaler=1, the PWM period is Tcyc(PR2+1) = 500ns*53 = 26.5us.
     * For 100% duty cycle, 
     * PulseWidth = PWMxDCH/L (10bits) * Tosc * 1(prescaler) giving
     * 26.5us/125ns=PWMxDCH/L = 212decimal 
     * PWMxDCH = d4h
     * PWMxDCL = 00h
     * 
     * For 75% duty cycle, the duty cycle registers must count off 26.5us*0.75=19.9us.
     * PulseWidth = PWMxDCH/L (10bits) * Tosc * 1(prescaler) giving
     * 19.9us/125ns=PWMxDCH/L = 159decimal 
     * PWMxDCH = 9fh
     * PWMxDCL = 00h
     */
    
    // 100% Duty Cycle on RA1
    PWM2DCH = 0xD4;
    PWM2DCL = 0x00;
    
    // Setting timer-0 for the generation of the delay
    TMR0 = 0;                // Set TMR0 to 0
    INTCONbits.TMR0IF = 0;   // Clear the TMR0 interrupt flag
    INTCONbits.TMR0IE = 1;
    INTCONbits.GIE=1;        /* Enable Global Interrupt*/
    
    OPTION_REGbits.PSA = 1;  // Assign No-Prescaler to TMR0 
    OPTION_REGbits.T0CS = 0; // Set TMR0 Clock source to FOSC
    
    /*
     * My formulas is:
        Fosc/4 = 8MHZ/4 = 2MHZ 

        period for a tick= 1 / 2MHZ = 0.0000005s

        time for 8 bit count = 0.0000005 * 256 = 0.000128s
     * 
     * Overflows every 128ms 
     * for one second delay loop cnt = 1000*(1/128) = 8
     * LC = 8*60 = 480 for 1 minute
     * LC = 480*60 = 28800 for 1 hour 
     * LC = 28800*12 = 345600 for 12 hours 
     */
    
}

void main(void) {
    setup();
    long int cnt = 0;
    
    while (1) {
        if (SWITCH == 1) {
            cnt = 0;
        }
        else {
            if (INTCONbits.TMR0IF == 1) {
                cnt += 1; // Reset the timer
                // 100% Duty Cycle on RA1
                PWM2DCH = 0xD4;
                PWM2DCL = 0x00;
                 
                INTCONbits.TMR0IF=0; // Reset Timer Interrupt Flag 
            }  
            
            // If 1 minute limit is reached (change this number to change the delay)
            if (cnt > 480) {
                // 75% Duty Cycle on RA1
                PWM2DCH = 0x9F;
                PWM2DCL = 0x00;
                
                // LED breathing effect
                for (int i=0; i<212; i++){
                    PWM1DCH = i;
                }
                for (int j=212; j>0; j--) {
                    PWM1DCH = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interrupts are enabled for TMR0, but I see no interrupt service routine. Does your "C" provide a default interrupt service?

Comment: it looks there's nothing constraining the rate of the while loop.

Comment: if PORTAbits is not declared volatile that could be a problem too.

Comment: hi thanks for your comment. I am honestly not sure. isn't the interrupt routine engaged with the PR and recount after every 8 bit count. Its coded in MPLAB X IDE. And yes the rate of while loop seems to be extremely fast i have to put a delay_ms for led breathing effect to work.